# Is there a way to compress/optimize jpg2000 images with Pillow/Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I'm creating an image conversion script with PIL and have noticed jpg => jp2 results in a much bigger file (sometimes more than double the size). For other file types, PIL has the optimize flag to try and make them as small as possible. Is there a way to do the same sort of optimization with jp2 files? Any information regarding why the jp2 files are bigger would be enlightening as well...I am under the impression jp2 is supposed to be faster. [image: test image]

The attached image is an example. As a jpg file, it's ~440kb. Once converted to jp2, it's over 3mb!

Comment: This question is off-topic because _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/)

Comment: JPEG doesn’t really have a ‘small as possible’ setting - you can choose reduced quality but IME you don’t really want to go for the worst possible quality Because it’s pretty useless. Did you try jpeg->jpeg (with a different filename of course) to check if PIL compression uses a different quality or compression setting (Resulting in a larger/smaller file than the original)?